# Metahuman plugin fails as MetahumanMeshTracker will not load

Tags: unreal-engine5

I have a problem where after I enable the Metahuman plugin in Unreal 5.2 my project will not load at all with the following error :

**Plugin 'MetaHuman' failed to load because module 'MetaHumanMeshTracker' could not be loaded.  There may be an operating system error or the module may not be properly set up.**

I have looked into the logs and it looks like the DLL MSVCP140_ATOMIC_WAIT.dll is reported as a missing import. As far as I am aware this is part of the C++ redistributable package so I have repaired/uninstalled/re-installed the C++ redistributable packages with no luck. I have also tried copying the DLL to the plugin folder etc.

Here is an extract of the log :

```
[2023.08.30-10.14.46:342][  0]LogWindows: Failed to load 'D:/Unreal/UE_5.2/Engine/Plugins/Marketplace/MetaHuman/Binaries/Win64/UnrealEditor-MetaHumanMeshTracker.dll' (GetLastError=1114)
[2023.08.30-10.14.46:342][  0]LogWindows:   Missing import: MSVCP140_ATOMIC_WAIT.dll
[2023.08.30-10.14.46:342][  0]LogWindows:   Looked in: ../../../Engine/Binaries/Win64
[2023.08.30-10.14.46:342][  0]LogWindows:   Looked in: ../../../../Projects/MoCapTester/Binaries/Win64
[2023.08.30-10.14.46:342][  0]LogWindows:   Looked in: D:\Unreal\Projects\MoCapTester\Binaries\Win64

.....

[2023.08.30-10.14.46:347][  0]LogWindows:   Looked in: D:\Unreal\UE_5.2\Engine\Binaries\Win64\LinuxArm64
[2023.08.30-10.14.46:347][  0]LogPluginManager: Error: Plugin 'MetaHuman' failed to load because module 'MetaHumanMeshTracker' could not be loaded.  There may be an operating system error or the module may not be properly set up.
[2023.08.30-10.14.51:205][  0]Message dialog closed, result: Ok, title: Message, text: Plugin 'MetaHuman' failed to load because module 'MetaHumanMeshTracker' could not be loaded.  There may be an operating system error or the module may not be properly set up.
[2023.08.30-10.14.51:205][  0]LogCore: Engine exit requested (reason: EngineExit() was called)
```

Error 1114 is defined as :

```
ERROR_DLL_INIT_FAILED

1114 (0x45A)

A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
```

I am trying to use Metahuman Mocap for a project and have even purchased an iPhone12 to do this but am stuck on this error. I have posted on the UE Forums with no responses.

If anyone could point me to an area for me to investigate or resolve this it would be greatly appreciated.

What I have tried so far :

- Looking into the project logs
- Repairing the MS C++ redistributable package
- Uninstalling ALL C++ redist packages (incl old ones)
- Re-Installing the latest C++ redist package from MS
- Copying the MSVCP140_ATOMIC_WAIT.dll to the local plugin folder
- Checking that MSVCP140_ATOMIC_WAIT.dll exists in the System32 Folder